# Clone a local git repo as if I had cloned from its remote

Tags: git

I have a local git repo that I cloned from a remote (github, say). The branches in this have associated upstreams that they pull and push from.

I'd like to make a new local copy of this repo so that I can be simultaneously developing on different branches locally.

I could just `git clone …` from the remote repo, but this will take a while over a slow link.

Instead, I'd like to `git clone` from the local repo, but have the effect be as if I had done a `git clone` of the remote. So, branches in the new copy will pull and push from the remote. For any other operation that needs a remote it will use the original remote.

How can I do this? … should I just `cp -r repo repo-clone`?

Comment: Your local repo probably has a few things that are different from the remote repo, e.g. local branches and other remotes, ignored files, various other configuration options and hooks come to mind, but there are also more subtle differences such as packets, commits that are no longer referenced, index, various data (e.g. commit resolution stored for rerere). You'll want to specify the amount of equivalence you want between a fresh clone and a `cp -r` copy.

Comment: Side note : perhaps you don't really want a new clone, but a new work tree. see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you actually don't want a new clone, but just checkout multiple worktrees for different branches, you might also consider [`git worktree'](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) instead.

---

If you really want to clone and save the time and bandwith for download, you do the clone form the remote as usual, but you add `--reference <local repository>` to use the Git objects from the local repository instead of downloading them from the remote. This will use the objects from the reference repository and not copy them, so it could happen that some Git cleanup deletes objects that you need in your second clone if you e. g. delete a branch in the reference repository that is still in the new repository and the commits are not reachable anymore in the reference repository. If you want to spend additional diskspace to overcome this, use additionally `--dissociate` to actually copy the objects from the reference repository.

Comment: Awesome, that's great, and thanks for the extra credit `git worktree` which sounds very useful. I'll be looking at that as I quite frequently want to create and drop additional working copies.

Comment: `git worktree` seems to be exactly what I want, and I'd never heard of it after using git for a couple of years with dozens of other team members. It seems not very well known, so thank you for brining it to my attention! You might even want to rephrase your answer to suggest that first as it seems like the right approach given the nature of the question. The other details are also very useful. Thank you for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: Or perhaps not? :-) `worktree` seems great, but doesn't like me to have more than one tree on the same branch.

Comment: Because it does not make too much sense to have multiple working trees for one branch. They would never be in sync really. Just make multiple local branches from the same base branch if you want to work on different topics in parallel.

Comment: That makes sense, except that I quite frequently make explorative changes on a branch, perhaps to test an idea or check behaviour when I force something. I'd still like to be able to switch back to the unperturbed branch, or to make alternative changes. And I don't want to need to think up a branch name for the poking about. Still looks like a good feature though, thank you.

Comment: Just name them playground1, playground2, ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can `git clone /local/git/repo` from the local repo and use

`git remote rename origin old_origin`

`git remote add origin <PATH>`

to add the remote repo.
and maybe delete the initial repo with

`git remote remove old_origin`

Use `git remote -h` for more information

Comment: Actually `git remote set-url ...` would be the combination of the `rename / add / remove` sequence. But anyway, cloning from the remote and using the local as reference repo should be the easier way.